# Navigating Career Ambiguity in IT: Lost in Transition Software/DevOps Engineer - Seeking Guidance on Next Steps

Tags: career-development, software-development

I've been working in IT consulting for the past 10 years, collaborating with clients on team projects lasting 6-12 months. My focus has predominantly been on building Cloud solutions and handling System Integrations within Agile/Scrum Teams. Over the years, I've played various roles such as Software Engineer, DevOps Engineer, and Cloud Engineer.

I started my career as a Software Engineer (.NET/C#) in 2013, gradually shifting my focus towards the cloud since 2019. The nature of my work evolved from traditional programming as a Software Engineer to more low code and specific infrastructure solutions in my roles as a DevOps Engineer. Despite feeling a sense of pride in my journey as a Software Engineer, I've observed shifts in the market dynamics, with less emphasis on traditional software development when building cloud solutions.

Presently, I find myself not as challenged in my current role. I've contemplated the idea of transitioning to a Lead Developer or Software Architect position. However, being inherently introverted, I struggle with active participation during team meetings, which is a crucial aspect of these roles. Another consideration was pursuing a career as a Trainer, but the energy cost associated with constant communication poses a challenge given my introverted nature.

In an effort to break the current career impasse, I've been attempting to be more proactive, though ideas for meaningful contributions don't readily come to mind. A further concern arises during Code Reviews where I find that I provide less feedback compared to when I am building solutions independently, where I tend to be highly critical.

Feeling somewhat stuck, I'm reaching out for ideas and suggestions on what steps to take next in my career. Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What would you like to do?

Comment: @Jay maybe you dislike (at least one of) the people you are working with right now, and just need a change of venue? It is hard for me to see how you could be lacking enough challenges in the work you mentioned, and why you are not just looking through job sites for interesting possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Being involved in low code infrastructure and dev ops does not lend itself to an easy transition to a Lead Developer or Software Architect position.  By its very nature, most low code operations do not desire to employ significant development teams.  You are also not going to always be involved in the process of converting business requirements into a solution, especially on the dev ops end.

Cloud dev ops and infrastructure skills are highly desired and highly portable.  There should be opportunities in supervision/management in companies large enough to have dedicated teams for infrastructure and dev ops.

On more general advice, be very careful picking leadership as a transition because your position does not provide enough challenge.  Leadership is an entirely different skillset and set of stresses.

Answer (score 0):

Natural transition at 10 years mark is ever senior professional + side consulting for fun and variety or executive route (Technology director, VP etc)

Translation: ;)
This is what I meant

At 10 year point in developer carries, most people i know went one of two routes.

1. Steady and stable senior professional position (Senior Dev, Team leader with team 3+ years old etc) and have consulting gigs on the side for fun and variety, not to get too bored and stay on top of new technologies
2. Executive route - Technical Director, VP of technology - meetings, policies development, projects specs and leading

You can decide what route would you want to go